# How does a UK analogue telephone detect that the caller has hung up (disconnected)?

Tags: analog, telephone, telecommunications

**Scenario**
This is a question regarding the **design** of UK analogue telecommunications equipment and the consequent **design impact** that is necessary for a router duplicating those signals. It is asked so that I can liaise with the designers of the router so that they can alter the **design** of the router to resolve the problem stated. This question is **not** about how to **use** a router or other equipment.

Here **in the UK** I have an analogue answerphone that worked perfectly when it was plugged directly into the old, analogue master socket and recorded messages finished immediately the caller hung up. Since March I now have a router with VOIP capability (Fritz!box 7530) that generates/receives UK analogue telephone signals at a FON socket, allowing old analogue phones and equipment to work using my new VOIP Internet connection.

**The problem**

Calls work fine with the analogue phones and an answer phone connected to the FON socket will record messages left by callers. However when the caller hangs up after leaving a message I get a series of beeps (number unobtainable tone?) recorded after the message for nearly a minute. I think this is until something times out and the resistance of the line goes up to almost open circuit, indicating there is no call in progress.

The issue seems to be that the router is not designed to generate the correct tone to indicate to the answerphone when the caller has hung up or, if it is, then the frequency or cadence of that tone is not quite right.

**Question**

Exactly what 'signal' does BT require to be designed into equipment and sent down the line when the calling party hangs up **a UK landline phone** (and which was previously being detected by my answerphone with no problems)?

If it is one of the usual tones such as number unobtainable or engaged then I'd like to know exactly what frequencies the design calls for and what cadence (mark/space between pulses) is used?

**Places I've already looked**

Lots of web sites and several questions on Stack Exchange. However most of these either refer to American systems or they don't say and are presumably American. I need the UK protocol.

**Further information**

I've been in contact with the German router manufacturer who are willing to alter **the design** of the router if they know exactly what to alter it to.

Comment: Can you tell us the frequency of the tone that you hear? An easy solution to do that is to install the (free, since designed by a university for scientific experimentation) [Phyphox App](https://phyphox.org/) on your smart phone and use the "Audio Spectrum" or "Frequency History" functionality.

Comment: That's a cool app! The tones I get are not continuous, they turn on and off, I get about 20s worth of 424Hz, with a mark space of 0.6s on, 0.2s off, followed by about 1 minute of 400Hz, 0.4s on, 0.25s off. That's almost a German busy tone except all their tones have equal mark space ratios. The second, 400 Hz period has the right frequency for UK but the wrong mark space ratio for any tone in Andy aka's table.

Comment: Did you try to contact AVM support for that issue?

Comment: Yes, (I mentioned this in my question). They said it sounds like the incorrect signals may be being sent by the Fritz!box FON socket and they would be willing to investigate the issue and make changes to the router if they knew exactly what signals the UK network sends to indicate to answerphones that the caller has hung up. - Hence my question here as part of my research into exactly what those signals are. At the moment there seems to be some disagreement and the signals that get recorded don't exactly match any of the suggestions.

Comment: As these tones vary between countries, maybe there's a more appropriate (i.e. UK) version of the firmware for the router

Answer (score 9):

> *I need the UK protocol*

[Wiki - Disconnect tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disconnect_tone#:%7E:text=A%20disconnect%20tone%20in%20telephony,tone%20(e.g.%20in%20UK).) gives you details for the UK: -

> **A disconnect tone in telephony is a tone provided to the remaining
> party to a call after the remote party hangs up. Typically, the
> disconnect tone is a few cycles of the reorder or busy tone (e.g. in
> US), or between five and fifteen seconds of the Number Unobtainable
> tone (e.g. in UK).**

So maybe your new system doesn't produce a number unobtainable tone that sufficiently matches what is hinted at above. The number unobtainable tone in the UK is a continuous tone of 400 Hz.

See [ITU Operational Bulletin No. 781 - 1.II.2003](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/inr/forms/files/tones-0203.pdf) for a list of all number unobtainable tones used throughout the world.

Comment: nice! Combining your table and my answer: German phones would hear a 425 Hz tone, and UK ones 400 Hz.

Comment: @OrangeDog your proposed changes weren't technically incorrect but, they were just formatting proposals that I have rejected because, they go against my choice to format my answers in the way I normally do things.

Answer (score 7):

Well, hm, analog telepone specifications are often a bit messy, as historically, network operators often were national, and they had the power to develop and type-approve on their own, so the way standardization happened was often following specific regional experiences with "yeah that's how we used to do it".

The relevant UK standard is British Standard BS 6305, which specifies how your British phone ought to work, electrically.

However, and that's what I mean with messy, the way phone and network interact used to be standardized by British Telecom PLC themselves, in SIN 351. I think you're looking for [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130617003810if_/http://www.sinet.bt.com:80/351v4p5.pdf), Section 7 "Call Clearing", specifically "7.2 Network Initiated Clearing":

> The BT network interface will provide a sequence of clearing signals at the NTP as a result of terminals ending a call or when terminals fail to present valid digits during call set-up.
> This will consist in any order of:
>
> a) an ‘end-of-call’ signal of between 90 ms and 130 ms and/or;
> b) number unobtainable tone lasting between 3 s and 20 s and/or;
> (Number unobtainable tone is described in SIN 350 [3] Network Tones and
> Announcements)
> c) silence lasting between 0 s and 30 s;
>
> and will end with the Parked State (see section 7.3 Parked State).
>
> Note 1: The ‘end-of-call’ signal is sometimes known as the “K-break” signal. It offers a positive way for automatic terminal equipment to determine when either a calling terminal or the BT network interface has resumed the off-line condition. The signal consists of a disconnection or a reduction in the loop current to below 1 mA for the time period stated.
>
> Note 2: There are certain interfaces supported by non-copper access systems that cannot provide the ‘end-of-call’ signal.

My bet is your answerphone is expecting a disconnect, so option a) from that list, but it gets b), and possibly in a different tonality than a British phone expects.

I know that at least in the early 1990s in Germany, a phone where the other end hung up would stay "on line" for more than a minute before the network disconnected the loop. So, that might be the case here.

Comment: You might be on to something.What gets recorded seems to be 32 cycles of the German busy tone (slow beeps) followed by 16 cycles of the German Congestion tone (fast beeps). Either that or it's the UK busy followed by the UK pay tone! with the recording end after about a minute.. Since the router is made in Germany, maybe  it not been set up for the UK

Comment: @user2834566 see my comment under your question!

Comment: I've added the results using that app

Comment: @user2834566 thanks! that's really nice of you :)

Comment: Practical experience suggests that old answerphones do indeed look for the electrical end of call signal (i.e. (a) above), whereas some VoIP equipment delivers tones instead. The tones should obviously be the UK ones (i.e. (b)) rather than the German ones, but I suspect you might need the electrical signal.

Answer (score 5):

This is called "calling party control", "far end disconnect", or in BT terminology "disconnect clear time". It consists of making the line open circuit (0 volts tip-ring) for a duration somewhere between 50 and 1000 milliseconds after the remote party hangs up. The duration varies quite a bit around the world, and the most likely problem is that the signal your ATA generates is *shorter* than what your answering machine is willing to recognize. In that case they simply need to make it longer (e.g. 500ms).

In some times and places, the disconnect signal was a polarity reversal, instead of open-circuit. This isn't used in the UK. A less likely cause is that the ATA is configured for the wrong standard entirely, or isn't signalling far-end disconnect at all. In that case it needs to be configured for the correct standard.

Comment: It's also called 'First Party Disconnect' but try as I might I cannot get a consensus on what the UK signal is. (polarity reversal - don't think that's used anymore; line resistance set  to several MOhm; line set to open circuit; busy tone - no, mark space is wrong; unobtainable tone - no,that's continuous not pulsed. etc.

Comment: @user2834566 open circut and "several MOhm" are really the same thing, and the tones come too late to be useful. Open-circuit is how we signal equipment that the call is over right away, intercept tones and howlers are how we let silly humans know that they left the phone off hook if they don't hang up within a minute or whatever.